# Google play services signature is invalid

Tags: android, google-play-services

I'm developing an Android application and used the Google play services SDK for implementing both Google Login and GCM.

according to the documentation, When running the application on devices which doesn't include the SDK, I should prompt the users using the following code:

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

On the first run everything goes fine. The user is prompt to d/l the Google Play Services application from the market.

After the SDK is installed, re-running the application yields the following error in LogCat:
Google play services signature is invalid.
Google play services in invalid. cannot recover

The error dialog shows the following error:
**Google play services, which some of your apps rely on, is not supported by your device. Please contact the manifacturer for assistence.**

This happens when I try to run the application on Samsung Galaxi Mini with Android version 2.3.6, with the latest Google Play store (4.3.11), and the google play services which is d/l to the device is 3.2.25 (761454-10).

Did anyone else is experiencing this issue? 
Can it be that this device is not supported at all, although it still lets the user d/l the Google play services application to the device?

Thanks

Comment: Have u tried to run another app using google play service on the same device?